Save WooCommerce custom product meta field value to order line item meta
I have a unique situation where I've created a custom meta field for products in WooCommerce and I can't get the value to save properly with the order line item meta when an order is placed.
Here is the code I'm using to achieve the custom meta field:
// Create field on product page admin
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'tpc_woocommerce_product_custom_fields' ); 
function tpc_woocommerce_product_custom_fields () {

    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
            array(
                'id'          => '_custom_product_merch_shop_cle',
                'label'       => esc_html__( 'Merch Shop Art', 'woocommerce' ),
                'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Enter CLE here', 'woocommerce' ),
                'desc_tip'    => 'true',
                'description' => esc_html__( 'Use to add CLE# for merch shops', 'woocommerce' ),
            )
    );
}

// Save field value with product
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'tpc_woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save' );
function tpc_woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save( $post_id ){

    $custom_field_value = isset( $_POST['_custom_product_merch_shop_cle'] ) ? wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_POST['_custom_product_merch_shop_cle'] ) ) : '';
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_custom_product_merch_shop_cle', $custom_field_value );

}

I've put it in the General tab and it shows for Variable and Simple type products which is all we use.
The field does not always have or need a value.
The value is for internal use only and doesn't need to be displayed on the frontend or to customers in any way or in any step of the ordering process.
Basically: when someone places an order that includes a product that has a value in this field, I'd like the field value at the time of ordering to be saved with the order line item meta. The goal is to be able to include this data in exports via the ID/key (_custom_product_merch_shop_cle).
Ideally I'd like to:

Make sure this code I already have is correct
Have this value displayed in the order details admin for each item in the order (only if a value is present)
[Most importantly] Have the value saved with each product's order line item meta

Lastly, if will be very rare that the values would change, but on the off chance they do, I would like all previous orders and order data to stay as the previous value and not inherit the new/replaced entered value.
Thanks for any help!

After searching for what seemed like days before posting my original question, I finally found a snippet I adapted to my needs that not only seems to save the custom field value to the order line item meta but also shows it in the order details admin.
// Add order line item
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'tpc_custom_checkout_create_order_line_item', 20, 4 );
function tpc_custom_checkout_create_order_line_item( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    // Get a product custom field value
    $custom_field_value = get_post_meta( $item->get_product_id(), '_custom_product_merch_shop_cle', true );
    // Update order item meta
    if ( ! empty( $custom_field_value ) ){
        $item->update_meta_data( 'Merch Shop Art', $custom_field_value );
    }
}

